# Time in x axis matplotlib overlap

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I plot bitrate in time with following function

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

def plotBitrate(time,bitrate,filename):
    time = [datetime.datetime.strptime(elem, '%H:%M:%S.%f') for elem in time]

    plt.plot(time,bitrate)
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.ylabel('Bitrate kbits/s')

    plt.autofmt_xdate()
    plt.savefig(filename, dpi = 300)
    plt.close()
```

Data looks like this

```
Time        bitrate
00:00:00.95 33528.2
00:00:01.47 30013.2
00:00:01.99 26238.5
```

But this time format results to overlapping ticks in plot

[image]

I tried to format the x axis so that it with the plt.autofmt_xdate() but this did not work, I get AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'autofmt_xdate'.

Is it possible to format the x axis so that the ticks don't overlap?

Best regards

Comment: There are several ways to make the ticks not overlapping: (a) Use a smaller font size, (b) use less ticks (i.e. show a maximum of N ticks), (c) change the ticklabels' orientation (e.g. to vertical). In which direction do you want to go here?

Comment: When I change orientation to ex plt.xticks(time,rotation=45) the time format is lost and is presented incorrectly. Maybe less ticks or max number of ticks is a better solution?

Comment: Have you tried `plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()`?

Comment: plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate() works as it tilts the ticks at a 45⁰ angle. Is it possible to format the time data so that matplotlib will reformat automatically depending on the data? For example with gnuplot I can use set xdata time and gnuplot will format the data correctly automatically. Is there a equivalent in matplotlib?

Comment: What do you mean by reformating? Is the data not correctly formated? Can you give an example? Could [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_index_formatter.html) be of some help?

Comment: The data is formatted correctly. But it would be nice if for example plot is in minutes then the milliseconds are not shown automatically. I will take a look at the link that mentioned.

The plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate() is good enough for now. Could you put that as a answer to the question and I will accept it.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`autofmt_xdate()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.autofmt_xdate) is indeed a good way of preventing overlapping labels. However, pyplot does not have this method, instead, it's a method of `figure`.

Therefore

```
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```

would do the job.