# How can plot 200 rows (time series) in matplotlib and make it readable in the x-axis?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Hey guys this is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np

banco=pd.read_csv('banco central3.csv',index_col='Fecha',parse_dates=['Fecha'], usecols=. 
['RRII','Fecha'])
print(banco.head())
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

ax.bar(banco.index.values,
    banco['RRII'],
    color='purple')


ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.WeekdayLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m-%Y'))


ax.set(xlabel="DATE",
   ylabel="RRII",
   title="\nReservas Internacionales")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The output, as a plot, is the following. The data (x-axis) is unreadable.

The datetime('Fecha') is about 200 rows. I want to clarity the X axis to become it readable.

and also i dont know why the barplot looks in that way (so separated among them). I want a classic barplot.

You see that the datatime is unreadable

[image]

the format of the data is this:

```
            RRII
Fecha             
2019-11-27  43.765
2019-11-28  43.736
2019-11-29  43.772
2019-02-12  43.731
2019-03-12  43.750
```

But i have 200 rows.

There is any way of making it? Thanks you very much

EDIT

I change the mdates.Daylocator to the m.dates.Monthlocator. and i added a Plt.setp function. Now my plot is not overlap but the line plot has no sense.

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())

plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=30, 
horizontalalignment='right')
```

IMAGE HERE. I want the plot follow the RRII by datetime

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time in x axis matplotlib overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41812646/time-in-x-axis-matplotlib-overlap) ... Quite a few more searching with variations of `python matplotlib x axis date overlap`

Comment: You are plotting the data points in the order they are in the csv, rather than by date. You should either sort your csv or do a smoothed scatter plot rather than a line plot.

Comment: and how can i make in a plot?

Comment: Please don't continually change your question based on answers you get - just ask a new question or search This isn't a discussion forum.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/visualization.html

Answer (score 0):

To make the x axis readable, change the line

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.WeekdayLocator())
```

to

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
```

However, the usage of barplot is not advisable with 200 rows; use a normal plot:

```
ax.plot(banco['RRII'], '.', color='purple')
```

[edit: changed marker from line point]

Comment: Yes! this work with the overlap. Thank you very much. But now i have a problem with the plot. I will upload it to the question

Comment: Use banco = banco.sort_index() before plotting to sort datetimeindex

Comment: Also make sure that index is an DateTimeindex with banco.index= pd.to_datetime(banco.index)

Comment: I have changed the plot marker from line to point. This should look better. But maybe the dataset has other issues.